# Declaring pointer to base and derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I just found that I am confused about one basic question in C++

```
class Base {

};

class Derived : public Base {

}

Base *ptr = new Derived();
```

What does it mean? ptr is pointing to a Base class or Derived class? At this line, how many memory is allocated for ptr? based on the size of Derived or Base?

What's the difference between this and follows:

```
Base *ptr = new Base();
Derived *ptr = new Derived();
```

Is there any case like this?

```
Derived *ptr = new Base();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the type system of C++, its important to understand the difference between *static* types and *dynamic* types.  In your example, you defined the types **Base** and **Derived** and the variable `ptr` which has a *static* type of **Base ***.

Now when you call `new Derived()`, you get back a pointer with a *static* and *dynamic* type of **Derived ***.  Since **Derived** is a subtype of **Base** this can be implicitly converted to a *static* type of **Base *** and assigned to `ptr` as the *static* types now match.  The *dynamic* type remains **Derived *** however, which is very important if you call any virtual function of **Base** via `ptr`, as calling virtual functions is always based on the *dynamic* type of the object, not the *static* type.

Answer (score 13):

For `Base *ptr = new Derived();` memory is allocated according to `Derived` class. `ptr` points to the object but the compiler is instructed to only "grant access" (visibility) to the members of the object that are declared in the `Base` class.

Of course the memory associated with the pointer `ptr` is the same i.e. independent of the object it is instructed to point to. Usually, the size of a "pointer object" is constant on a CPU architecture e.g. 32bits / 64bits (or smaller on embedded devices for example).

For `Derived *ptr = new Base();`: no, this is invalid.

Class `Derived` isn't just a class `Base` but is defined as *deriving* from `Base`: hence, a pointer instance to a `Derived` object instance can't be just assigned to an object instance of class `Base`.

---

You might consider perusing the very good Wikipedia contributions [on Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and [Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(computer_science)).

Comment: so what's the type of *ptr? Base or Derived? What's the advantage to make it as a pointer to Base?

Comment: @skydoor: it relates to Polymorphism (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming): you could have different derived classes that share a base class.

Comment: @skydoor-It's more flexible since a Base pointer can point to *any* object derived from a Base class.

Answer (score 4):

[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

ptr is a pointer; it has the same size regardless of what it points to.

Answer (score 4):

On a 32-bit system, 4 bytes of stack space are allocated for `ptr`. On a 64-bit system, it would be 8 bytes. (Assuming that the compiler doesn't decide to leave it in a register and not allocate any stack space at all).

The reason you can let a pointer to a `Base` point to a `Derived` is one of the basic principles of OOP - polymorphism. A `Derived` *is* a `Base`. You can stick it in anywhere a `Base` could be used.

Your last line (`Derived *ptr = new Base();`) is invalid because a `Base` is *not* a `Derived`.

Comment: True. I was working under the assumption that this was a function-local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question hits on one of the most important parts of object-oriented programming: [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism).

`Derived` is a subtype of `Base`.  That means that everything that `Base` can do, `Derived` can also do.  Often, `Derived` is more specific than `Base`: it works on a subset of what `Base` does, but it does that subset much better than what `Base` does.

Think about an example.

Think about writing a graphics program.  You might have a class, `ClosedShape`, and a method inside it, `fill()`.  It's possible to create a very generic method that can fill any closed shape... but usually, that method will take memory, and it might be slow.

You might have another class, `Square`.  Now, filling squares is very easy and very fast: it's two nested for loops.  Since `Square` does everything that `ClosedShape` does, it can inherit from `ClosedShape`.

Why is polymorphism important?  Think about many different kinds of `ClosedShape`: triangles, hexagons, and so forth.  If you want to fill all of them, just do:

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    cs[i].fill();
}
```

They all will use their own version of `fill()`!

Comment: Nope. Inheritance has to do with method and field lookup. What you describe is Polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

For Base *ptr = new Derived(); memory is allocated according to Derived class. ptr points to the object but the compiler is instructed to only "grant access" (visibility) to the members of the object that are declared in the Base class.

Of course the memory associated with the pointer ptr is the same i.e. independent of the object it is instructed to point to. Usually, the size of a "pointer object" is constant on a CPU architecture e.g. 32bits / 64bits (or smaller on embedded devices for example).

For Derived *ptr = new Base();: no, this is invalid.

Class Derived isn't just a class Base but is defined as deriving from Base: hence, a pointer instance to a Derived object instance can't be just assigned to an object instance of class Base.

Answer (score 0):

A `Derived` object is appended to the end of the `Base` object, so the prefix [in bits] of `Derived` is actually a `Base`, so there is no problems to assign a `Derived*` object to a `Base*` variable. It is perfectly safe to access any of `Base`'s fields/methods of the `Derived` object.

However - the oposite is not true. If you assign the address of the `Base*` to a `Derived*` variable and then access one of the fields of `Derived` [which is not in `Base`] you will get out of the allocated space.

**Typing reasoning:**

Also note that a value can be assigned to a variable only if it is of the correct type without casting [c++ is [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) langauge]. Since `Derived` is a `Base`, `Derived*` is a `Base*` - so this is not conflicting, but the other way around is not true.

I highly recommend to read [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4937234/4990642) to understand the logic as well