# C++: Deriving with variables. Something is wrong with a small section of code

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

Classes `Dog` and `Cat` derive from `Animal`, which in turn derives from `Creature`. Also `pDog`, `pCat`, `pAnimal`, and `pCreature` are pointers to their class. `Animal` and `Creature` are both abstract classes.

What is wrong with my code?

```
pAnimal = new Dog();
pDog = pAnimal;
```

Comment: Not every cat is Socrates.

Comment: While we appreciate that you trimmed your code down to the section that is causing the problem, you trimmed *too much*. Can you show the declaration of your variables `pAnimal` and `pDog`? Also the class declarations (just the part that illustrates the inheritance)

Comment: lol that's pretty good

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong from the code you posted? What's the exact error you get?

Comment: I'm guessing type-mismatch assigning `Animal*` to `Dog*` ?

Comment: Consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937180/a-base-class-pointer-can-point-to-a-derived-class-object-why-is-the-vice-versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert *up* a hierarchy (i.e., from derived to base) implicitly.

Converting *down* the hierarchy (from base to derived) has to be done explicitly. In most cases, you want to use `dynamic_cast` so the conversion will only succeed if correct:

```
Animal *pAnimal = new Dog();

Dog *pDog = dynamic_cast<Dog *>(pAnimal);
```

Note that your classes need to contain at least one virtual function for this to work (but if you don't have virtual functions, the hierarchy probably doesn't make sense at all).

Comment: The destructor makes a good candidate for a virtual function if you don't have one already.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming `pAnimal` is of type `Animal*` and `pDog` is of type `Dog*`.

When you assign the `new Dog()` to `pAnimal`, it casts the `Dog*` to an `Animal*` which is perfectly legal, since `Dog` derives from `Animal`.

Going back the other way (i.e. casting from `Animal*` to `Dog*`) is different however. Since there are situations where this would be an invalid cast (i.e. if `pAnimal` pointed to a `Cat`), the compiler requires that you explicitly cast it, for example:

```
pDog = static_cast<Dog*>(pAnimal);
```

You will want to use `dynamic_cast` if you aren't sure of the type, for example:

```
pDog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(pAnimal);

if (!pDog)
{
    // invalid cast, pAnimal didn't point to a Dog
}
```

`dynamic_cast` will check if the cast is valid, and if not it will return a null pointer.

**Edit:** using `static_cast` may give a slight performance gain over `dynamic_cast`, however should only be used if you are 110% sure of the type.

Comment: You don't *need* to use `dynamic_cast`, but you risk undefined behavior if you use any other style of cast.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` only works if `Animal` has at least one virtual function. If you don't have any so far, making the destructor virtual is a good choice

Answer (score 0):

You are hoping that the compiler will *remember* that a `Dog` is always the type pointed to in your code.

**In general**, you can't assign any old `Animal *` to a `Dog *`.

**In your specific case**, C++ will follow the **same general rule**.  The compiler will not scan your code to see if `pDog = pAnimal;` *might* be allowable.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that `pAnimal` is `Animal*` and `pDog` is `Dog*`, then you have a type mistmatch caused by the fact that an `Animal*` is not convertible to `Dog*` indipendently from the dynamic type of the object.

You can:

- downcast via `static_cast` if you are sure about the dynamic type of the object pointed to
- downcast via `dynamic_cast` if you are not sure

Comment: `static_cast` only works if the base is non-virtual.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How can you statically know the containing object if it is only determined at runtime?

Comment: @KerrekSB _" How can you statically know the containing object if it is only determined at runtime?"_ I didn't meant exclusively determined at runtime (e.g. using a CRTP). Anyway `static_cast<>` works for virtual and non virtual classes, may be your wording is a bit misleading.

Comment: @KerrekSB That clarified a lot. I was mistaking `virtual` base for base class with `virtual` function.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No. That's a *polymorphic class*, as opposed to a *virtual base*. A derived class with a virtual base is always polymorphic, though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The unifying theme is of course that "virtual" means "determined at runtime".