# Explain the concept of Implicit Derived Class Object to Base Class Object Conversion using pointers

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, type-conversion

Explain the concept of Implicit Derived Class Object to Base Class Object Conversion using pointers.

Is the reverse also possible? If yes, what is the phenomenon called?

Comment: The phenomenon is known as insincere homework

Comment: help me @ArdentCoder. I don't know the answer to this ques..It will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you some short points, you can use it to explain the concept yourself.

First of all, I hope you know what [implicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) is.

In this scenario, a pointer to a base class object is required to point to an object of derived class. You can see: [A Base Class pointer can point to a derived class object. Why is the vice-versa not true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937180/a-base-class-pointer-can-point-to-a-derived-class-object-why-is-the-vice-versa)

Actually that question contains the answer to the first part of your question, **the reverse is not true**.

Coming to the phenomenon, that pointer can take *multiple forms*. **Polymorphism**.